# windows 10 showing me that bWAPP contains a reverse shell

Tags: penetration-test, bug-bounty

i have downloaded bwapp from official site and windows 10 defender showing me that it contains a reverse shell ( i know these things are there for practice ) but in earlier days it is not showing that. Is it good to use it is safe to use

Or it is just a False Positive

[image]

Comment: False possitive.

Comment: I agree that it's _likely_ an expected result (false positive) rather than actual malware but I hope someone out there can answer definitively. (A lot of Google searching hasn't netted me anything more informative than this page, so far.) Despite its age the included vulnerability list is impressive and suggests there's still a lot of educational meat left on that bone (assuming everything is fairly well executed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good to use it is safe to use

From the description:

> bWAPP, or a buggy web application, is a free and open source deliberately insecure web application.
> It helps security enthusiasts, developers and students to discover and to prevent web vulnerabilities.
> bWAPP prepares one to conduct successful penetration testing and ethical hacking projects.

No, it's not secure. It's not meant to be secure. It's ***explicitly*** meant to be insecure, as a tool for training. You should ***not*** host it in a way that is world accessible. Host it on your local computer, accessible locally - or even better - in a disposable virtual machine. Heck, they even provide a [pre-configured  VM that you can download](https://www.mmebvba.com/sites/bwapp/download.htm).

It should be noted that it's 6-7 years old now, so it's outdated. The learning value from it may not be as great as in 2014, as many attacks are mitigated by current technologies and best practices...

Comment: thank you for the answer but here i am referring secure as is it secure to run in my windows locally because in earlier days reverse shell warning is not there maybe they updated it.

Comment: It probably is. I would *expect* it to contain a remote shell vulnerability...